# how will i pass the path of a file name to void *buffer using c language?

Tags: c

implementing ProcessRequest and wants to copy data into buffer to return to the caller

The function signature is he following :
`int ProcessRequest(HCST hCST, void *buffer, short tag, short status)`

path name of the file is stored in `char src [40]`;

Comment: If you use `src` in the call to `ProcessRequest`, it should work. I don't understand what problem(s) you are facing.

Comment: src contains the file path. i want to copy in void *buffer. how can i do it. please help.@R Sahu

Comment: Do you want to pass `src` into the function? Or are you implementing `ProcessRequest` and want to copy `src` into `buffer` so that the caller of the function has access to that value? Your question is really not clear.

Comment: @AlanAu :  i Want to implement ProcessRequest and want to copy src into buffer so that the caller of the function has access to that value. this is my question

Comment: Assuming `src` is a string then just use [strncpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy). But `ProcessRequest` as defined is not safe for that purpose. The best practice is to pass in a "length" parameter for the size of `buffer`. Otherwise your function implementation will be open to buffer overflows as it will not know how much buffer space it has to write to.

Comment: @AlanAu : can i use something like below.                          memset(buffer,(int)' ',sizeof(buffer));

Comment: Of course not! That doesn't reference `src` at all so how can that possibly copy `src` into the buffer? Also, `buffer` is a `void *` and `sizeof(void *)` will only give you the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes) and not the size of the entire buffer as you presumably want.

Answer (score 0):

You need this :

```
int ProcessRequest(int hCST, void *buffer, short tag, short status)
{
  // stub function 
  static char test[] = "Test";
  strcpy(buffer, test);
  return 0;
}

...
char src [40];
...
ProcessRequest(myhCST, src, mytag, mystatus);
/* now src contains "Test" */
```

This code is very simple and unsafe because `ProcessRequest` doesn't know the size of `buffer` and hence may potentially overwrite past the end of `buffer`.

Comment: It's abunduntly unclear from the OP's original question (hence all the downvotes I guess). But the comment trail shows OP is actually implementing `ProcessRequest` and wants to copy data into `buffer` to return to the caller.